# How to set the right movement speed to the Sprite(flash)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

```
            if(sprite.status == 'moveBack')
            {
                var pointX:Number = mouseX + Math.cos(sprite.angle) * 100;
                var pointY:Number = mouseY + Math.sin(sprite.angle) * 100;
                dx = pointX - sprite.x
                dy = pointY - sprite.y;
                var angle:Number = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
                var dist:Number = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                if(dist < 1)
                {
                    sprite.status = 'free';
                }
                else
                {
                    sprite.x += Math.cos(angle) * 15;
                    sprite.y += Math.sin(angle) * 15;
                }
                trace(dist);
            }
sprite.angle += 0.05;
```

this is a short snippet of code, so here one of the sprite object are coming back to the position they was before, the point to where he is coming, is moving everytime, and the problem is: lets say my speed is 15 pixels/per frame, and my movieclip is near to the end point he is coming, and the remaining distance is 20 then if my speed is 15, 20 -15 = 5 and then 5 - 15 = -5, but i am using the pythagor formula and the distance is always positive, so the sprite can't reach 0 distance and then be free, what can i do in this situacion?

Answer (score 0):

What I'll tend to do for myself in this situation is just check if distance remaining is equal to or less then the velocity on every step. Then if it is, just set the speed to the remaining distance.

Comment: how you calculate that speed?

Comment: your speed would be the distance you are moving the sprite by every tick

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in a more sophisticated behavior where the moving object slows down and stops at the target position, I recommend using steering behaviors: http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/gdc99/

In this case, you're looking at the **arrival** behavior.